# Additional luggage fee from US to Europe with a domestic connection

Tags: luggage, connecting-flights

I have a single ticket from Little Rock, AR airport to Paris CDG (France).

Reservation was done on Air France website, first flight is operated by Delta from Little Rock to Atlanta and has a DL tracking code, while the second is Air France operated with an AF code.

I wish to bring an additional luggage (1 carry-on and 2 checked), so I'll have to pay a fee.

However, do I need to pay the fee twice or do Air France and Delta have a baggage agreement and I'll only pay it to Delta ? I couldn't find this information online, was only able to find the fees.

Thanks

Comment: It's an AF itinerary booked by AF. Have you asked them?

Comment: Not yet, I was wondering if maybe it was common info, that could be found. I'll ask them I guess. Thanks

Comment: The SE Q-and-A format encourages folks to research their questions before posting, and to let readers know what they've done. Read more here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Generally you will pay the carrier your purchased from. When doing your online check-in, if you see the option of buying additional luggage, then you can do it there and just bring the receipt (although it will be on file too) when you go to the airport to get your luggage tags.

Now, if the option is not offered to you, you will pay it at the check-in counter which will be the one from Delta. Luggage fees are per way, so you will be 1 or 2 pieces (depending if your ticket had 0 or 1 in its included allowance). You will pay a similar fee on your return, either again when checking-in with AF or at the Air France counter, since they operate the first lag of your return flight.

Comment: So I'll only pay once if my understanding is correct. This is the second round of the trip, I didn't need an additional luggage for the first way. I'll call them and then accept your answer if it matches. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you will only pay them once since you are only returning.

Comment: @Itai The online checkin could well be with the operating carrier of the first leg.

Comment: *Generally* no but it is possible. That's why I said *generally*.for the online checkin and the converse for checkin a the airport.

Comment: @Itai *Generally*, when I fly on a  LH ticket with a UA codeshare as the first leg, I have to check in online on the UA website.  Indeed, checking in online anywhere else then on the operating carriers website is likely much more of a pain as seat selection might not work well, not recognize your FF status, and so forth.